# Update hidden field on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments, stripe.js

I am using Stripe.js to create a token. I want to pass this token to the next page via a hidden field. Unfortunately, the hidden field doesn't update onchange as it should do.

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_pTMOD3umdVw9RkEYB35tz28X');
var elements = stripe.elements();

var card = elements.create('card', {hidePostalCode: true});
card.mount('#card-element');

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input.field');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    input.classList.add('is-focused');
  });
  input.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    input.classList.remove('is-focused');
  });
  input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    if (input.value.length === 0) {
      input.classList.add('is-empty');
    } else {
      input.classList.remove('is-empty');
    }
  });
});

function setOutcome(result) {
  var errorElement = document.querySelector('.error');
  errorElement.classList.remove('visible');

  if (result.token) {
    document.getElementById("cc_token").value = result.token.id;
  } else if (result.error) {
    errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    errorElement.classList.add('visible');
  }
}

card.on('change', function(event) {
  setOutcome(event);
});

document.querySelector('#registrationForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  stripe.createToken(card).then(setOutcome);
});
```

`setOutcome` works when I call it, but it does't get called properly onchange.

Comment: At what moment should it have triggered the `change` event?

Comment: @acdcjunior
`card.on('change', function(event) {
  setOutcome(event);
});`

Comment: I mean: that *listens* to the event. Something else would *trigger* it.

Comment: @acdcjunior `stripe.createToken(card).then(setOutcome);` can trigger the change required

Comment: It seems to work for me: https://codepen.io/acdcjunior/pen/mxrgYX?editors=1010 no?